# How to design android BLE flow with device that is already bonded?

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am currently working with a solution where i store previous bondeddevices. I am now trying to design a flow where i can use them in the app but i am unsure what i exactly need to do.

The first time i see a device (before storing its info), i first connect to it and then make a bonding.

The second time a user opens the app i intend for it to work directly with this previously bonded device but i am unsure what i need to do. Do i need to connect again to the device that i once bonded with and if so, what will i need, only the port?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether your devices are bonded or not has not so much with connection establishment to do in Android's API. You always need to connect to a device using the connectGatt method on a BluetoothDevice object in order to obtain a BluetoothGatt object that you use for communication with the device.

Comment: Okay, and yes i will communicate through gattservices. Maybe the first image might be the correct design flow then. Where i connect with the stored bonded port that i've stored locally.

Comment: Or maybe i first read device data with the port, and then after i will make the connection so i can get gattservices?

Comment: What is a "port"?

Comment: the adress of the bonded device